# maven-jetty-plugin for jetty 7.3 and forward

Tags: maven, jetty

Where is maven-jetty-plugin for jetty 7 ?

Do you have a working pom?

Do I need another repo rather than default repo1 from maven ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Roo generated project, for Jetty 8.0, I've this in the `build` section of my `pom.xml` (`<project> <build> <plugins> <plugin>`)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1.v20110908</version>
    <configuration>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I guess that [other versions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin) would work too. If it doesn't work, here is my full repository list. Maybe you can identify which one does the trick adding one at a time and share us back...

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: but, which repositories do you have? it is not in default maven repos.

Comment: I see, I copy you my repository section in the answer

Answer (score 2):

The `maven-jetty-plugin` was renamed to `jetty-maven-plugin` at version 7.0.0.pre5.

Maven coordinates for the old one: [maven-jetty-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mortbay.jetty%7Cmaven-jetty-plugin%7C7.0.0.pre5%7Cpom)

Maven coordinates for the NEW one: [jetty-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.jetty%7Cjetty-maven-plugin%7C9.0.0.M4%7Cmaven-plugin)

Both are available from the default maven repository.

*NOTE: You need to use Maven 3 for jetty-7.5.3 and later releases.*